# Error running .Net and SQL tests in dbfit

Tags: c#, sql-server, fitnesse, fitsharp, dbfit

I have a simple C# Column fixture class which independently tests fine.
I have a sql server table which again, independently tests fine.
If I test both, testing the SQL table first, again all is OK.
However if I test the C# first, then the SQL test fails 'Type 'Connect' not found in assemblies'

So this works fine...

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!define PATH_SEPARATOR {;}

!path fitsharp/fit.dll
!path fitsharp/dbfit.sqlserver.dll

!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
!|Connect|Data Source=localhost;integrated security=SSPI;Initial     Catalog=Test2|
!|Query| select Colour from dbo.Colour|
|Colour|
|yellow-orange|

!path Fixtures.dll

!|Fixtures.SampleDo|
|firstPart|secondPart|together?|totalLength?|
|Hello|World|Hello, World|10|
|Houston|We Have a Problem|Houston, We Have a Problem|24|
```

... but this fails by simply moving the Fixtures.dll test ...

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!define PATH_SEPARATOR {;}

!path Fixtures.dll

!|Fixtures.SampleDo|
|firstPart|secondPart|together?|totalLength?|
|Hello|World|Hello, World|10|
|Houston|We Have a Problem|Houston, We Have a Problem|24|

!path fitsharp/fit.dll
!path fitsharp/dbfit.sqlserver.dll

!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
!|Connect|Data Source=localhost;integrated security=SSPI;Initial     Catalog=Test2|
!|Query| select Colour from dbo.Colour|
|Colour|
|yellow-orange|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The original solution described below does not work for DbFit.  Here is a workaround:

In your fixture `SampleDo`, you can include the following to let `SqlServerTest` handle the rest of the tables in the test:

```
public override bool IsVisible { get { return false; } }
```

**Original answer:**

When using DbFit, the table

```
!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
```

is usually the first table in the test so it becomes the "System Under Test" and subsequent tables like

```
!|Connect|Data Source=localhost;integrated security=SSPI;Initial     Catalog=Test2|
```

are interpreted as methods to be executed on `SqlServerTest`.

If it is not the first table, something else will be the "System Under Test", in your case, `SampleDo`, and FitNesse will look for a method `Connect` on `SampleDo`.  To make `SqlServerTest` the "System Under Test" part way through the test, use the with keyword:

```
!|with|new|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
```

Comment: Its certainly got me closer but now I'm getting a different error..

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at fitSharp.Fit.Engine.CellProcessorExtension.Get[V](CellProcessor processor)
   at dbfit.DatabaseTest.Query(String query)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at fitSharp.Machine.Model.TypedValue.ThrowExceptionIfNotValid()
   at fitSharp.Fit.Operators.InterpretFlow.ProcessFlowRow(Tree`1 table, Int32 rowNumber)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a workaround as there is a bug in DbFit that causes the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply Mike.  I've added the override as suggested (and removed the "with|new") but I'm afraid I'm now back to the original "Connect not found in assemblies" error :(

Comment: You sir, are an absolute star!!! :D
Thank you for your time, patience and expertise.